# rails mysql recording impressions for a page

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, impressions

**I will make my question very simple.**

I have a ruby on rails app, backed with mysql.

1. I will click a button in page-1, it will goto page-2 and list a
   table of 10 company's name.
2. Now, this list of ten companies are randomly generated(based on the
       logic behind that clicked button in page-1) from COMPANIES table
       which has 10k company names.
3. How do I calculate the count of the number of times a COMPANY name
       being displayed on page-2, for a day.

   Examaple: At the end of day - 1
   **COMPANY_NAME | COUNT**
   A            | 2300
   B | 100
   C | 500
   D | 10000

*Now, from the research I have done, raw inserts will be costly and I learned there are 2 common ways to do it.*

1. Open an unix file, write into it. At the end of the day, INSERT the content to the database.
   Negative : File system if accessed concurrently, it will lead to lock issues.
2. Memcache the count and bulk insert into the DB.

### What is the best way to do it in rails?

### Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Can you give me any links which explains how to implement it and discusses its advantages as well..?

Comment: How many times will page-2 be displayed on a day? Seems you are looking for optimizations that are probably not necessary. I doubt your load will be so high that just using the database will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

use redis. redis is good for maintaining in-memory data. It has atomic increment (an other data structures)